# Force on a dielectric medium

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

Under the influence of an external electric field the dipoles in a dielectric medium arrange themselves. These dipoles will create a field that opposes the external field, resulting in a net field that is 1/k times of the external field (where k is the dielectric constant). So my doubt is, can other types of force such as magnetic force (in case the dielectric is moving perpendicular to an external magnetic field) arrange the dipoles in a similar way such that the force becomes 1/k times?

For example let's take a cuboidal dielectric with dielectric constant **k**. The dielectric moves with a constant velocity **V** in a region of uniform magnetic field **B** that is perpendicular to the direction of it's motion.

A force of **q**(**V**X**B**) acts on a charged particle **q** in the absence of a dielectric medium. Does the net force per unit charge become (**V**X**B**)/**k** in the dielectric?

Can the dipoles arrange themselves under the influence of any force, or can they arrange themselves only due to an electric field?

Comment: What do you mean by "oppose net force" ? In physics bodies do not oppose force, they experience force due to some body or field, and in the first case, usually act with reaction force back on that body.

Comment: I meant that under the influence of an external electric field the dipoles in a dielectric medium arrange themselves. These dipoles will create a field that opposes the external field, resulting in a net field that is 1/k times of the external field (where k is the dielectric constant).  So my doubt is, can other types of force such as magnetic force (in case the dielectric is moving perpendicular to an external magnetic field) arrange the dipoles in a similar way such that the force becomes 1/k times?

Answer (score 0):

In a dielectric medium you should use the induction vector  $$\vec{D}=\epsilon_0 \vec{E}+\vec{P}=\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r \vec{E}$$
Considering the Coulomb force between two pointlike particles in vacuum
$$F_0=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_1q_2}{d^2}$$
become
$$F_m=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}\frac{q_1q_2}{d^2}$$
As rule of thumb you can multiply $\epsilon_r$ at $\epsilon_0$ where the latter appears to get the equation in the matter but technically you must do the analysis using $\vec{D}$ instead of $\vec{E}$.
For instance, to evaluate the electric field in matter use the Gauss theorem $\nabla \cdot \vec{D}=\rho$ instead of $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$

Comment: if a dielectric medium is moving with some velocity under an external magnetic field , can we say that the magnetic force in the dielectric becomes 1/Er times

Comment: In this case you should use the maxwell equations in matter, involving the fields $\vec{D}=\epsilon_0\epsilon_r\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}=\frac{\vec{B}}{\mu_0\mu_r}$